# Does keras predict function store the hidden state from previous sequence if I have stateful = True when training the model?

Tags: keras, lstm, predict, recurrent-neural-network

So far I have learned that when turning on the stateful = True option, the hidden state from one sequence will be passed to the next sequence as its initial hidden state. So after I train such a model on a time series data, say I have 1000 time periods, I used the first 800 to train and validate my model, then I would like to use the model on the last 200 samples (to make a one-step ahead prediction), will the hidden state output from the 801st sample be passed to the 802nd sample as its initial state? How about the 803rd sequence, etc?

Any insights will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the answer?

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I was not sure about what you said so I spent some time doing some testing. Please see the details below.